# Apollo server subscription middleware

Tags: server, apollo, subscription

i pass currentuser auth to app middlware and it works just fine... but when i run subscription in graphql its saying current user not found.... what i am doing wrong guys ? when i remove just currentuser from apollo server it works...i was trying to follow docs from apollo website to create this

ive tried move logic to the body of apollo server but it didnt work out for some reason

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const cors = require('cors');
require('dotenv').config({ path: 'variables.env' });
const app = express();
const { createServer } = require('http');

const corsOptions = {
    origin:'http://localhost:8000',
    credentials:true
};

mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use(async (req , res , next) => {
    const token = req.headers["authorization"];
    if(token !== "null"){
      try{
          const currentUser = await jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET);
          req.currentUser = currentUser;
          console.log(currentUser)

      }catch(err){
          console.log(err)
      }
    }
    next();
})


const Event = require('./models/Event');
const User = require('./models/User');
const Message = require('./models/Messages');

const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server-express');

const { typeDefs } = require('./Schema');
const { resolvers } = require('./Resolvers');


mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {useNewUrlParser: true , useCreateIndex: true})
  .then(() => console.log('DB connected'))
  .catch(err => console.error(err))


  const SERVER = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    context: ({req, res}) => ({
         Event,
         User,
         Message,
         currentUser:req.currentUser
      }),

    playground: {
      settings: {
        'editor.theme': 'dark'
      }
    }
  });

SERVER.applyMiddleware({ app , path:'/graphql' });

const httpServer = createServer(app);
SERVER.installSubscriptionHandlers(httpServer);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

httpServer.listen({ port: PORT }, () =>{
  console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:${PORT}${SERVER.graphqlPath}`)
  console.log(` Subscriptions ready at ws://localhost:${PORT}${SERVER.subscriptionsPath}`)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case of subscriptions, you're using web sockets instead of regular http requests, so your token is available elsewhere, namely under `connection.context.Authorization` (note the uppercase 'A'), `connection` being provided by the function attached to the `context` of your ApolloServer and being defined in the context of subscriptions.

You basically will want to move token verification to your ApolloServer declaration:

```js
  const SERVER = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    context: ({req, connection}) => ({
         Event,
         User,
         Message,
         currentUser: async () => {
           const token = connection
                         ? connection.context.Authorization
                         : req.headers.authorization
           return await jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET)
         },
      }),
    ...
```

This is a really bare bones example, you could check for the existence of `req` as well and generate an error if neither `connection` nor `req` are set, handle the case where there is no token, etc., but you get the basic idea.

See [Context with Subscriptions](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/subscriptions/#context-with-subscriptions) in the Apollo Server docs for further reference.